# How to configure granular privileges in MarkLogic to permit updates to the configurations of a specific database only, while excluding all others?

Tags: marklogic

I'm seeking guidance on configuring granular privileges in MarkLogic to allow updates to database configurations for a specific database only, excluding others.

For example, I have a user named 'custom-rest-admin' with the roles `rest-writer`, `rest-admin`, and `manage-admin` assigned for a specific REST API. The database in question is named `MY_DATABASE_NAME`. Using the following command, I successfully updated the database properties:

```
curl --anyauth --user custom-rest-admin:pass -X PUT -d@"./database-config.json" -i -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/MY_DATABASE_NAME/properties"
```

However, due to the broad scope of the `manage-admin` role, I found that I could also update properties for other databases, as demonstrated here:

```
curl --anyauth --user custom-rest-admin:pass -X PUT -d@"./database-config.json" -i -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/OTHER_DATABASE_NAME/properties"
```

I've reviewed the section on Granular Privileges in MarkLogic's documentation but haven't found specific guidance on this scenario: [MarkLogic Granular Privileges](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/security-guide/en/granular-privileges.html).

Could someone provide instructions or code examples on how to achieve this level of granularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of granting `manage-admin` role, can create an appropriate [fine-grained privilege](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/security-guide/en/granular-privileges/understanding-granular-privileges.html), assign it to some role, and then assign that role to the user.

Find the ID of the MY_DATABASE_NAME database that you want to grant privileges for, and use it to grant a privilege with that ID.

For example, if the MY_DATABASE_NAME ID was 123456, then grant:

```
http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/123456
```

https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/security-guide/en/granular-privileges/categories-of-granularity/privileges-to-administer-a-specific-resource.html

> A privilege of this category grants a user an ability to administer a specific resource (for example, a database with the specified identifier). This privilege is granted by suffixing the administrator privilege for that kind of resource (for example, "database") with the specific identifier (for example, database-ID ), which results in the specific privilege (for example, http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/database-ID). This privilege may imply the privilege to read and write a portion of a configuration file. It also grants the ability to call various built-in functions for specific resources (for example, http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-forest-clear/forest/forest-ID privilege allows calls to xdmp:forest-clear() for that forest identifier).

- http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/database-ID

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
Access to the `/manage/v2` endpoint is not permitted without the `manage-admin` role. Instead, the XQuery code examples found on [this MarkLogic documentation page](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/security-guide/en/granular-privileges/examples-of-granular-privileges-usage/scenarios-that-use-granular-privileges.html) were helpful.
When setting the privilege, specifying the database name also worked.

```
{
  "privilege-name": "my-database-updater",
  "action": "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/MY_DATABASE_NAME",
  "kind": "execute"
}
```

---

Thanks Mads. I already tried that but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Is the update endpoint still the same or is there a rest-api endpoint instead?

```
curl --anyauth --user custom-rest-admin:pass -X PUT -d@"./database-config.json" -i -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/MY_DATABASE_NAME/properties"
```

I found my database ID using this command:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:pass -X GET -i -H "Content-type: application/json" "http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/MY_DATABASE_NAME?view=status&format=json"
```

Defined my custom privilege using the database ID and I've assigned the privilege to the user's role:

```
{
  "privilege-name": "my-database-updater",
  "action": "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/admin/database/2415296184985150668",
  "kind": "execute"
}
```

The database-config.json I tested is this simple one:

```
{
  "trailing-wildcard-searches": true,
  "range-element-index": [
    {
      "scalar-type": "string",
      "namespace-uri": "",
      "localname": "type",
      "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
      "range-value-positions": false,
      "invalid-values": "reject"
    }
  ]
}
```